# spring DelegatingFilterProxy can't find filter-name bean in web.xml when using AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

My **web.xml** looks like this

```
<!--listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener-->

<filter>
    <filter-name>webContextFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>webContextFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I commented out the JBoss `SpringContextLoaderListener` above to avoid an `IllegalStateException` because I am using a subclass of `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` elsewhere (from a mandatory library) which itself creates the root application context.

When I run this under **tomcat7**, I get a

> SEVERE: Exception starting webContextFilter
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'webContextFilter' is defined

The `applicationContext.xml` contains the appropriate `component-scan` definitions, so that's not the problem.

I am guessing maybe the context loader from `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` is not yet started when DelegatingFilterProxy is created??

How can I fix this?

**EDIT1**: The `webContextFilter` bean is in the right package, i.e. subpackage of the one listed in `context:component-scan`, and the bean is defined as

```
@Component("webContextFilter")
public class WebContextFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
// ...
}
```

The bean is in a WEB-INF/lib/xyz.jar.  This all used to work under tomcat6 when the JBoss resteasy `SpringContextLoaderListener` was uncommented in web.xml.

**EDIT2:** Perhaps my question boils down to this:  when using `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` to create the root context, how do I specify additional filters, since the ones in web.xml don't seem to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the applicationContext.xml was not being read, so I added `@ImportResource` annotation to the `SecurityConfig` class definition.

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml")
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm! But I wonder if the right way is to use DelegatingFilterProxy

Answer (score 0):

`DelegatingFilterProxy` is a proxy that delegates to spring managed bean. name of a bean that should be registered in container is `webContextFilter` in your case. `Bean` should implement `Filter` interface. This excerpt is taken from `javadoc` of `DelegatingFilterProxy`

> Proxy for a standard Servlet 2.3 Filter, delegating to a
>   Spring-managed  * bean that implements the Filter interface. Supports
>   a "targetBeanName"  * filter init-param in {@code web.xml}, specifying
>   the name of the  * target bean in the Spring application context.  * 
>   *
>
> {@code web.xml} will usually contain a {@code DelegatingFilterProxy} definition,  * with the specified {@code
>   filter-name} corresponding to a bean name in  * Spring's root
>   application context. All calls to the filter proxy will then  * be
>   delegated to that bean in the Spring context, which is required to
>   implement  * the standard Servlet 2.3 Filter interface.  *  *
>
> This
>   approach is particularly useful for Filter implementation with complex
>   * setup needs, allowing to apply the full Spring bean definition machinery to  * Filter instances. Alternatively, consider standard
>   Filter setup in combination  * with looking up service beans from the
>   Spring root application context.

If you have this bean in your context, then please update your question with bean declaration and tell number of containers you're using

Comment: I have added EDIT1.  I am not sure how to find the number of containers.  This is a webapp composed of several dependent jars in WEB-INF/lib.