# DelegatingFilterProx With javax.servlet.Filter Not Working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-security

In my web.xml I created the following filter:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>tokenAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>tokenAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

And I created the following component:

```
@Component("tokenAuthenticationFilter")
public class TokenAuthenticationFilter implements Filter
{
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TokenAuthenticationFilter.class.getCanonicalName());

    @Autowired
    private IAMUserDAO iamUserDAO;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException
    {
       //Code comes here
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
```

Unfortunately, this filter is never accessed and I don't know why. Please help

Answer (score 0):

My initial need was just to add a filter to an existing application using DelegatingFilterProxy given that my filter was annoted with @Autowired properties. I initially try to modify the web.xml per [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762091/spring-delegatingfilterproxy-cant-find-filter-name-bean-in-web-xml-when-using-a); however this didn't work for me.

- My next step was then to create an
  AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer that will
  eliminate the web.xml configuration altogether.
- In order to do so, I had to use java configuration and translate all my xml configurations files to java configurations; servlet-context.xml became SpringWebConfig.java and root-context.xml, SpringRootConfig.java
- I then created this class and everything works as planned:

  ```
  public class AuthenticationBWebInitializer extends 
      AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected Filter[] getServletFilters () {
        DelegatingFilterProxy filterProxy = new DelegatingFilterProxy();
        filterProxy.setTargetBeanName("tokenAuthenticationFilter");
        return new Filter[]{filterProxy, new AppLog4jFilter()};
  }

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] { SpringRootConfig.class };
  }

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] { SpringWebConfig.class };
  }

  @Override
  protected String[] getServletMappings() {
      return new String[]{"/"};
  }

  @Override
  protected void registerContextLoaderListener(ServletContext servletContext) {
      super.registerContextLoaderListener(servletContext);    
  }
  ```

  }

Hopefully this will help some lost souls out there with the same issue.